# antdesign has-feedback icon outside of form

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, antd, ant-design-pro

I am facing the issue where the `has-feedback` icon shows outside of the input box for form groups.
[image]

Sample code:

```
              <a-input-group size="large">
                <a-row :gutter="10">
                  <a-col :span="12">
                    <a-form-item has-feedback>
                    <a-input
                      size="large"
                      placeholder="Business name"
                    >
                    </a-input>
                    </a-form-item>
                  </a-col>
                  <a-col :span="12">
                    <a-form-item has-feedback>
                    <a-input
                      size="large"
                      placeholder="Last name"
                    >
                    </a-input>
                    </a-form-item>
                  </a-col>
                </a-row>
              </a-input-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed the `<a-input-group size="large"></a-input-group>` tags, this error went away.